# How can I make a complex active record query efficient?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app that has a tags, a chapters and a relationship table called chapter_tag_map between them.

I want to have a query in the tags controller to get popular tags.

Basically get the total number of chapters that have been tagged by each tag and then sort them by chapters descending.

But for the view I want to use the Tag objects in the view.  What I have now is:

```
tags = ChapterTagMap 
  .select("tag_id, count(tag_id) as chapters")
  .group("tag_id")
  .order('chapters desc')

@tags = items_for_current_page(tags)
  .map {|tag| Tag.find(tag.tag_id)}

#items_for_current_page is a helper method for pagination (gets the right set of 50 items)
```

Is there a way to get the tag objects more directly, without using map?  Or is there a way to make this more performant?

Comment: So a tag can have many chapters?

Comment: Yes its a many to many relationship

Comment: Moving the sql from your application code to a database stored procedure might have merit.

Comment: You can always do `Tag.find(tags.map(&:id)).paginate(params[:page])`, assuming you will use something like kaminari

Comment: konrad, im not at the moment, but I guess thats another point I should look at. dan, thanks for the advice. My database knowledge is rather lacking, so I will have to look this up